# Data serialization format for Standard ML

Tags: serialization, sml

I am looking for a way to write compound data (e.g. lists) to a file that can later be read back into the program. In Lisps, this is simply a matter of writing s-expressions to a file, and reading it back in later (using `write` and `read` for Scheme; `prin1` and `read` for Common Lisp). Is there a similar method for doing this in Standard ML? Is there anything built-in that can help? (By "built-in", I mean something that is part of the language or basis library).

Comment: You may wish to read this: [Serializing to JSON in SML/NJ](https://medium.com/@harrison.grodin/serializing-to-json-in-sml-nj-3b01f20e7462)

Comment: SML/NJ library has these serialization formats: JSON, s-expressions, XML.